# How do I enter Unicode characters in TeX?

Tags: unicode

I need to write a few Unicode characters (e.g. `Л`) into a text without using e.g. XeTeX, LuaTeX or `inputenc`oding with UTF-8 (please assume as little as possible about the typesetting system).

I have read other questions regarding this problem, but did not find an answer without 
XeTeX/LuaTeX/UTF-8/... (therefore the explicit TeX in the question).

**EDIT** (because it is way too long for a comment and comments do not provide code markup):

Egreg's answer works perfect with TeXlive 2011 (as expected for an answer of egreg and for TeXlive; +1 for that). Also as expected, with "Old-TeX" (SWP5.5 @ http://www.mackichan.com, which is the recent version) it does not work. Additionally it is necessary to install the [cyrillic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cyrillic) and [lh](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lh) packages and to change the code to

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\CYRL\cyra\CYRT\cyre\CYRK\CYRS}%
\end{document}
```

(There *must* be an empty line before `\documentclass`, which SE does not show.)
Then the document does compile even with SWP, but `Л` still is not shown. The reason (as found by Ulrike Fischer) for this is that 
the needed `tfm` font file (`larm1000.mf`) cannot be generated by the "Old-TeX". 
When generating it with TeXlive and copying it to SWP, it is still not used.

Thus: With the current version of SWP it is not possible. :-(

Nevertheless, it is possible to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\def\cylatex{%
%TCIMACRO{LaTeX}%
%BeginExpansion
{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\CYRL\cyra\CYRT\cyre\CYRK\CYRS}%
%EndExpansion
}

\begin{document}

Text\cylatex{}Text

\end{document}
```

(There *must* be an empty line before `\documentclass` again, which SE does not show.)

When compiled with modern LaTeX, it writes `TextЛаТеКСText` 
(I'm not sure about `КС` for X - anyone speaking a language using cyrillic signs here to help?), 
and when compiled with SWP it writes `TextLaTeXText` (which is better than having just `TextText`).

Caveat: When the document is opened with SWP and saved, the definition will be changed to

```
\def\cylatex{LaTeX}
```

therefore the main document may never be saved by SWP (using subdocuments and editing those is possible).

Placing the

```
\def\cylatex{%
%TCIMACRO
...
}
```

into a style file will result in SWP reading the `{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\CYRL\cyra\CYRT\cyre\CYRK\CYRS}` 
part and again creating an error instead of `ЛаТеКС` or `LaTeX`.

Comment: Well either you didn't install the lh-package correctly or your system is so old that it can't generate tfm's on-the-fly. What do you get on a terminal from `kpsewhich larm1000.mf`?

Comment: What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I don't know about SWP and the structure of the TeX system it uses. Maybe it's possible to copy into it the `.tfm` files needed (by running the file on TeX Live, that will produce them), but printing is another thing. :(

Comment: Good question! I know of no document as such that lists the LICR available for all official encodings. :( But looking at `t2aenc.def` you at least find the names of the cyrillic letters. In general `zzzenc.def` is the file to examine, where `zzz` stands for the encoding name converted to lowercase.

Comment: Sorry, no. The developers of the cyrillic encodings chose the placement of glyphs in a very different way than Unicode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every character in one of the standard output encoding has a LaTeX Internal Character Representation (LICR). The LICR for л is `\cyrl` and the character belongs to the output encoding T2A (cyrillic). So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} % T1 can also be OT1
\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\cyrl} is the cyrillic letter ``ell''}

{\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont\cyrl}l

\end{document}
```

will do. Of course you'll want to define a more handy command for choosing a different output encoding.

Comment: I changed `\cyrl` to `\CYRL\cyra\CYRT\cyre\CYRK\CYRS` to have some upper case letters as well, and `\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}` and `section` can be removed to keep the example minimal.
Would you care to adapt your answer? Maybe include the necessity of `Cyrillic` and `lh` packages, because they are necessary regardless of TeXlive or SWP?